# Can I call jquery.ajax() with some other function?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTables plugin, it has one event, that on click of button we can add new row in table.
The jQuery code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
var counter = 1;
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
    t.row.add( [
         counter,
        '<select id="k'+counter+'" name="itemname'+counter+'" ><option>-------</option></select>' ,
        '<input id="itemrate" name="itemqty'+counter+'"  placeholder="Quantity"  type="text">',
        '<input id="itemrate" name="itemrate'+counter+'"  placeholder="Rate"  type="text">',
        '<input id="totalamt" name="totalamt'+counter+'"  placeholder="Total Amount"  type="text">'
                ] ).draw();
                counter++;
            }); 
    });
```

I want to fill data fetched from a MySQL database using jQuery `.ajax()`, and my code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#k'+counter).click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'getData.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'form_data='+val,
            success:function(results){
                jQuery('#k'+counter).html(results);
            }
        });
    }); 
    });
```

The code for **getdata.php** is as follows:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('eroyalsum');

$sql = "SELECT ITEMCODE,ITEMNAME FROM itemmaster1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'" >'.$row[1].'</option>';
}

?>
```

Finally, my problem is when I write it as separate function, it just works only once. When I add other row it does not work, and when i write jQuery's `.ajax()` in one function it does not work...

Comment: What do you mean precisely by `it not work`?

Answer (score 0):

try changing you selector from:

```
jQuery('#k'+counter).click(function(){
…
```

to

```
jQuery(document).on("change", "select[id^='k']", function(){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the event binding.

When you bind the event to the #k elements, the new item doesn't automatically get the event bound to it.

You can use stuff like :

```
$('body').on('click','.new_elements',function(){ //dostuff});
```

you can read more about it here

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)